Windows 11 upgrade has wrecked my registers and now I cannot start BFE
Let me go over a simple timeline to summarize my issues.
For clarity: initial Windows 11 upgrade went OK. The services broke when performing an "upgrade and shut down" at the end of the day. Came on the next day and it was not good
In order:

Purchased a legitimate Windows 10 Pro license circa 2019

Last year (Late 2023/Early 2024) I got the notification that I can upgrade to Windows 11

Upgraded and everything seemed fine for a month or so

Small update was pushed and I updated and restarted

Internet does not work on ethernet or Wifi and there is a watermark on my screen to activate windows and it says I have an illegitimate license

I eventually find that my registries got messed up. I copied the ones from another computer and internet worked for ethernet (that is the only one I fixed).

Used my internet connection to repair windows 11 to fix registers

Now wifi works as well, but it still tells me I have illegitimate windows 11 (however, the watermark is gone)

I use my computer casually for school for a month, but eventually need to download cisco vpn

Cisco vpn does not install

Researching why, I find my firewall is inactive.  Says I need to update my firewall settings,

I click "Use recommended settings" and it gives an error: Windows Defender Firewall can't change some of your settings. Error code 0x8007042c

After some research I find Base Filtering Engine (BFE) is set to automatic, but not started.

Try to start BFE and it gives: Access Denied Error 5.

Confirm with my laptop that the PC registers for BFE look the same

I change permission in registry for BFE and add 'Everyone' and set the permissions to all then apply then OK then restart PC.

My BFE still does not start with Error 5: Access Denied error on Local Computer


Now this is where I am. Any ideas to go forward? I want to start BFE and enable firewall and get it to know I have a legit windows. Maybe the order I am doing things is wrong? Any help would be appreciated.
Edits to the original
Not sure when it happened, maybe during Windows Reinstall, but my Windows says Active currently so I guess it is legit now. However, I still am unable to run the command for installing a cisco VPN on my machine and the problems trace back to BFE not being able to start because of Error 5: Access Denied when I try to start it.
Current issue: BFE is not starting and because of this Winows Defender cannot start and is unable to restore to default settings.
Updates
Ran Offline Defender scan. Cannot find the file and was unable to download the defender app in teh microsoft store. I just ran the command through a terminal and it ran it and restarted. Came up and issue persisted (unable to start BFE)

Your computer is too loused up to continue with the current setup. It really seems like the computer is infected with a really nasty virus. Run deep antivirus scans by Defender and Malwarebytes, and if any problem is found then format the disk and install from scratch using a Windows 11 boot media from Microsoft (and no other source). It's also possible that you bought a fake Windows 10 serial if the source wasn't Microsoft.

A non legitimate copy of Windows wouldn’t have become activated.

I ran the offline scan and no change. I cannot find the report. I will see if Malwarebytes comes up with anything.  I did, however, find out that I am unable to install the defender app through microsoft store. I instead ran it through a terminal.
And as Ramhound said, the Windows 11 is now activated so I don't think it is an initial licensing issue.

I ran MalwareBytes and it came up with 30 PUPs. Mostly Chrome related. I quarantined all and tried things again. Issue persisted.

PUP's are likely not an issue. Other malware would be, and is likely to be impossible to remove. Since there are other issues, best chance is start over.  Download the ISO (Win 10 or 11), remove all partitions (booting from USB), and install.

Do you perhaps mean "registry"? Note that the "registry" is never referred to as "register" in Windows or regarding Windows, so using this other term is confusing. As the others note, your computer is messed up. Copying a REGISTRY from one computer to another is NEVER a good idea. Restoring a backup from the same computer CAN work, but it also tends to be a stop-gap or bandaid solution that you must fix, usually through a complete clean reinstall of the OS. PUPs are the most minor of possible annoyances, they are not viruses. A real virus will hide itself, but your OS may also just be broken.

Your OS is so far gone the best solution for you is to perform a clean, complete reinstall, entirely wiping the existing storage. If you back anything up, back up individual data files. Do NOT backup any entire folders or applications. While we cannot be sure, there is a good chance that running without a firewall or antivirus has resulted in a serious and deep viral infection, and backing up too much or too broadly will bring that infection over.
So, download a clean ISO of the Windows license you're authorized for, create a USB bootable installer, boot your computer to that and while in the Windows installation menu DELETE all of your current drive's partitions, to force the OS to completely ignore and remove any and all existing data on the drives.
After you have successfully reinstalled Windows, use MBAM and Windows Defender to thoroughly scan any files you did back up before you restore them to your freshly reimaged computer.
